# Use a very long UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

is there a simple way to **scroll an UIView**?

I want to do a registration form, but there are a lot of fields and i prefer to scroll uiview (with touch) vertically.

How can i do it?

thanks,
alberto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your fields into a `UITableView`, which resizes and scrolls for you. A table view is a more standard approach to setting up forms on iOS — it will be more familiar to end users.

Comment: See Apple's excellent documentation for an overview and examples: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: There's a custom class available here: http://icodeblog.com/2011/01/04/elctextfieldcell-a-useful-tableviewcell-for-forms/

Answer (score 0):

There is an UIScrollView object you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the height and width of the UIScrollView as per your requirement.

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,0,320, 500);
```

Comment: No, i already have a uiscroolview with 720px Height, but i don't able to scroll it on uiview.